# Hide de path in broswer

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, jboss

How can I hide the directory paths in my JBoss server with a aplcação Java EE JSF + Primefaces + Hibernate.
When I access the path is exposed for example `localhost:8080/client/create.xhtml`  Use filters to restrict unauthorized access, but would like suggestions on how to hide the path in the browser.

Comment: http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/

Comment: What do you mean by "*How to hide the path in the browser.*"?